# How to get asynchronousy without new threads or async and await keywords but only Task

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I wonder how to accomplish the same thing the below program does without using extra threads or  `await` and `async` keywords but only Tasks. A sample code would be awesome. It seems to me that we need to use `TaskCompletionSource` and `Async` versions of the IO-bound operations or any long-running operations.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Task t = Go();
  Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
  Task.Delay(1000).GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(() => { Console.WriteLine("Completed"); });
  Console.ReadLine();
}

static async Task Go()
{
  var task = PrintAnswerToLife();
  await task;
  Console.WriteLine("Done");
}

static async Task PrintAnswerToLife()
{
  var task = GetAnswerToLife();
  int answer = await task;
  Console.WriteLine(answer);
}

static async Task<int> GetAnswerToLife()
{
  var task = Task.Delay(2000);
  await task;
  int answer = 21 * 2;
  return answer;
}
```

Comment: Please check http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/BUILD2011/TOOL-829T it is not an easy task

Comment: @zahir Seems a nice link. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a pretty straightforward translation of `async` / `await` into `Task` by using `ContinueWith`. Other translations are also possible, e.g., `Task.Delay` becomes `System.Threading.Timer`.

The basic pattern is, for any `async` method that does an `await`:

```
static async Task Go()
{
  var task = PrintAnswerToLife();
  await task;
  Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

becomes:

```
static Task Go()
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
  var task = PrintAnswerToLife();
  task.ContinueWith(_ =>
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    tcs.SetResult(null);
  });
  return tcs.Task;
}
```

Correct error handling is a lot more work.

Comment: There is actually one more thing, `ContinueWith` should work in the same synchronization context of the original method.

Comment: Good catch. In this example, it doesn't matter, but normally `ContinueWith` should take `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`.